# wget works with .de domain but not .com

Tags: linux, wget, domain

When I open this site in my browser http://www.montratec.com/

it automatically gets changed to https://www.montratec.de/de/

I want to download files from the website http://www.montratec.com/ using wget and the original link. When I try this:

```
wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd www.montratec.com
```

it doesn't download anything and ends quickly

```
--2021-07-10 10:36:55--  http://www.montratec.com/
Resolving www.montratec.com (www.montratec.com)... 134.119.247.151
Connecting to www.montratec.com (www.montratec.com)|134.119.247.151|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.montratec.de/ [following]
--2021-07-10 10:36:55--  https://www.montratec.de/
Resolving www.montratec.de (www.montratec.de)... 134.119.247.151
Connecting to www.montratec.de (www.montratec.de)|134.119.247.151|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.montratec.de/de/ [following]
--2021-07-10 10:36:56--  https://www.montratec.de/de/
Reusing existing connection to www.montratec.de:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.tmp.html’

index.html.tmp.html                                [ <=>                                                                                              ] 104.09K  --.-KB/s    in 0.09s   

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2021-07-10 10:36:56 (1.15 MB/s) - ‘index.html.tmp.html’ saved [106585]

Removing index.html.tmp.html since it should be rejected.

FINISHED --2021-07-10 10:36:56--
Total wall clock time: 1.0s
Downloaded: 1 files, 104K in 0.09s (1.15 MB/s)
Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.
```

However, when I run the same command with the .de extension it seems to work and download content.

```
wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd www.montratec.de
```

Is it possible to modify the command such that it automatically checks all domains? I want to keep using the original .com link.

Comment: The .com website redirects to the .de version. That's a choice made by the website owner and not yours to ignore

Comment: Yeah but how can I download its content using wget if I only have the .com link with me and I don't know about  the .de one. I have to run this for a list of websites where I wont necessarily know if .de is the right site. Does that make sense? @roaima

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. You can see that the website redirects. Work with it.

Comment: The website directs in the browser, but does not automatically download its (.de) content on the terminal @roaima

Comment: You asked `wget` to download a copy of the .com website. It did that for you. If you want a copy of the .de website you need to tell it so

Comment: Is there no way to automatic redirect from .com to .de through the wget command? Like it happens in the browser? @roaima

Comment: You can use `-S` to remove the per-domain restriction. But if there's a single link to Google somewhere on any of the sites you intend to download you will end up downloading the Internet. You would be better fixing your source site address